# Format of numbers in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, formatting

I wrote the below lines:

```
rang1 = Range[0.0, 0.4, 0.02]; rang2 = Range[0.5, 1.0, 0.1]; 
caten = Catenate[{rang1, rang2}];
```

I see

```
caten
```

> ```
> {0., 0.02, 0.04, 0.06, 0.08, 0.1, 0.12, 0.14, 0.16, 0.18, 0.2, 0.22,
>  0.24, 0.26, 0.28, 0.3, 0.32, 0.34, 0.36, 0.38, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6,
>  0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.}
> ```

But I want to have `0.00` instead of `0.` and `1.00` instead of `1.` Moreover about `0.3` to `0.30` and so on.

How can I reach this goal?

Also, when I copy them to another cell of a Mathematica notebook I encounter to

```
{0.`, 0.02`, 0.04`, 0.06`, 0.08`, 0.1`, 0.12`, 0.14`, 0.16`, 0.18`,
0.2`, 0.22`, 0.24`, 0.26`, 0.28`, 0.3`, 0.32`, 0.34`, 0.36`, 0.38`, 
0.4`, 0.4`, 0.5`, 0.6000000000000001`, 0.7000000000000001`, 0.8`, 
 0.9`, 1.`}
```

But I don't wish to have the above cell after copy and pasting. I wish to gain the original format of the **modified** `caten` as  `{0.00, 0.02, 0.04, 0.06, 0.08, 0.10, 0.12, 0.14, 0.16, 0.18, 0.20, 0.22, 0.24, 0.26, 0.28, 0.30, 0.32, 0.34, 0.36, 0.38, 0.40,  0.50, 0.60, 0.70, 0.80, 0.90, 1.00}` (even after copy).

Comment: Look up [`NumberForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberForm). ``NumberForm[number, {Infinity, 2}]`` or ``NumberForm[list, {Infinity, 2}]`` should do what you want.

Comment: However, don't include the `NumberForm` in the variable definition. Use parentheses to isolate the definition from the display. `(caten = Catenate[{rang1, rang2}]) // NumberForm[#, {5, 2}] &`